# Using thread to write and select to read

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets

Has any one tried to create a socket in non blocking mode and use a dedicated thread to write to the socket, but use the select system call to identify if data is available to read data.

if the socket is non blocking, the write call will return immediately and the application will not know the status of the write (if it passed or failed).

is there a way of knowing the status of the write call without having to block on it.

Comment: Check the return code of write and you know if it was successful and how many bytes were written.

Answer (score 2):

> Has any one tried to create a socket in non blocking mode and use a dedicated thread to write to the socket, but use the select system call to identify if data is available to read data.

Yes, and it works fine.  Sockets are bi-directional. They have separate buffers for reading and writing.  It is perfectly acceptable to have one thread writing data to a socket while another thread is reading data from the same socket at the same time.  Both threads can use `select()` at the same time.

> if the socket is non blocking, the write call will
>   return immediately and the application will not
>   know the status of the write (if it passed or failed).

The same is true for blocking sockets, too.  Outbound data is buffered in the kernel and transmitted in the background.  The difference between the two types is that if the write buffer is full (such as if the peer is not reading and acking data fast enough), a non-blocking socket will fail to accept more data and report an error code (`WSAEWOULDBLOCK` on Windows, `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` on other platforms), whereas a blocking socket will wait for buffer space to clear up and then write the pending data into the buffer.  Same thing with reading.  If the inbound kernel buffer is empty, a non-blocking socket will fail with the same error code, whereas a blocking socket will wait for the buffer to receive data.

`select()` can be used with both blocking and non-blocking sockets.  It is just more commonly used with non-blocking sockets than blocking sockets.

> is there a way of knowing the status of the write
>   call without having to block on it.

On non-Windows platforms, about all you can do is use `select()` or equivalent to detect when the socket can accept new data before writing to it.  On Windows, there are ways to receive a notification when a pending read/write operation completes if it does not finish right away.

But either way, outbound data is written into a kernel buffer and not transmitted right away.  Writing functions, whether called on blocking or non-blocking sockets, merely report the status of writing data into that buffer, not the status of transmitting the data to the peer.  The only way to know the status of the transmission is to have the peer explicitly send back a reply message once it has received the data. Some protocols do that, and others do not.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way of knowing the status of the write call without having
>   to block on it.

If the result of the `write` call is `-1`, then check `errno` to for `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.  If it's one of those errors, then it's benign and you can go back to waiting on a select call.  Sample code below.

```
int result = write(sock, buffer, size);

if ((result == -1) && ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno==EWOULDBLOCK)) )
{
    // write failed because socket isn't ready to handle more data.  Try again later (or wait for select)
}
else if (result == -1)
{
    // fatal socket error
}
else
{
    // result == number of bytes sent.
    // TCP - May be less than the number of bytes passed in to write/send call.
    // UDP - number of bytes sent (should be the entire thing)
}
```